# A strange iframe inside JQuery official website

Tags: jquery, html

I am curious about the iframe sit at the bottom of JQuery official site (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This is its `HTML` snippet; anybody knows its function?

```
<iframe name="easyXDM_DISQUS_net_default744_provider" id="easyXDM_DISQUS_net_default744_provider"...
```

Answer (score 2):

The iframe is probably used to load [Disqus](http://disqus.com) comments; the comments you see at the bottom of any jquery docs page